# why I am getting old password in a password field in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am making a asp.net website where an user can change password .. by clicking a button `changepassword` i am redirecting to a new asp page where i have a user code field and a old password filed and a new password field like this:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="User Code: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtusercd2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Enter Old Password: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtoldpwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Enter New Password: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnewpwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Re-Enter New Password: "></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtrepwd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblmsg2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="float:right">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnchngpwd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Save.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now the problem is when i am redirecting to that page my code filed and old password is getting populated by the user login details 
i dont want to populate the old password filed . what shold i do?

Comment: I don't think someone can deduce the problem by looking at this html. There must be something that you are doing in CS level that is causing the behavior. Give some details on that

Comment: Show the code behind part, maybe you are setting it there or any script which you are using ?

Comment: nothing ... i am using nothing ... my `.cs` file is empty ... that's why i am asking here i am not writing any code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the webbrowser auto-populating it for you. Add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to each `<input />` element that is being inappropriately filled.

Comment: well sir my control is `asp` control so i am not getting `autocomplete` attribute

Comment: He means [`AutoCompleteType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autocompletetype%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)